# building lsd slam in xubuntu 16.4

Tags: build, ros, slam

I have cloned lsd_slam from github [this link](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam)
in section 2.2 of the README file the auther wrote that ros required, so I followed the instruction as it mentioned there :

> We do not use catkin, however fortunately old-fashioned CMake-builds 
> are still possible with ROS indigo. For this you need to create a rosbuild workspace (if you don't have one yet), using:
>   
>   sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
>   mkdir ~/rosbuild_ws
>   cd ~/rosbuild_ws
>   rosws init . /opt/ros/indigo
>   mkdir package_dir
>   rosws set ~/rosbuild_ws/package_dir -t .
>   echo "source ~/rosbuild_ws/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
>   bash
>   cd package_dir

but when I reach at the stage of initializing, this error is what I face:

> kave@kave-ThinkPad-X201:~/dev/rosbuild_ws$ rosws init . /opt/ros/indigo
>   Using ROS_ROOT: /opt/ros/indigo
>   ERROR in config: Is not a local file, nor a valid URL [/opt/ros/indigo] : unknown url type: /opt/ros/indigo

I dont know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROS Indigo will not work with Ubuntu 16.x [ref](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html). You can either roll back your version of Ubuntu to 14.x and install ROS Indigo and try again, or install ROS Kinetic on your current system and try building one of the versions of [lsd slam](https://github.com/kevin-george/lsd_slam) built for ROS Kinetic.